# How to make OAuth(Authorization Code Flow) work for Websites

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, adfs

I have a website which i want to be implemented under the same oAuth protocol as my current mobile apps are. The identity server which is used is ADFS3.0.

In authorization code flow, i get a code with the Redirect_URL maintained at ADFS Server. 
On Websites, Whenever user logs in on the oAuth credentials screen, browser gets redirected to the REDIRECT_URL with the code.
For example, www.redirecturl.com?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Now, how to go to the actual website from this point.

The website is written in C#
( Note: I know how to read and validate tokens, which i have used for my mobile apps, but what about websites)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly the same flow except that the redirect URL points to the website.

Note that ADFS 3.0 only has limited OAuth support (essentially web API).

Use ADFS 4.0 if you want OpenID Connect etc.